# Access 4d matrix JS opencv

Tags: javascript, opencv, matrix

I'm using electron with openCV with [opencv4nodejs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/opencv4nodejs).

I have a `4d` Matrix object and I want to access the 4 dimension elements of this matrix. The `at` function is not working: `mat.at(0,0,0,1)` is equal to `mat.at(0,0,0,2)` and they are both equal to `mat.at(0,0,0,0)` which I know is the true value.

This makes sense since the [openCV c++](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html) matrix documentation shows that `at` function can get at most 3 parameters `int i0, int i1, int i2`.

How do I access the `4d` elements in a matrix?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to access any element in dimension higher than `3d` you will need to use the `at` function and pass it an array. Here is the formal [c++ documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#a15c649a94cf2e06240b32b025231301f) of the function.

For example:

```
var element1234 = myMatrix.at([1, 2, 3, 4]);
```

Will work.